# Error while clicking Hyperlink

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview, datagrid, datagridviewcolumn

I have DataGrid in WPF which has column which contains HyperLink items which when clicked display those images. When i click Hyperlink my image gets displayed but i get this error.[Image of Error is Attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APnlo.png) .

Below is a xaml for DataGridView Hyperlink Column.

```
    <DataGridHyperlinkColumn Header="CNIC" Binding="{Binding s_man_image}" Width="100" >
                <DataGridHyperlinkColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <EventSetter Event="Hyperlink.Click" Handler="DataGrid_Click" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGridHyperlinkColumn.ElementStyle>
            </DataGridHyperlinkColumn>
```

And this is code for DataGrid_Click Event

```
    private void DataGrid_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var hyperlink = e.OriginalSource as Hyperlink;
        if (hyperlink != null)
        {
            Process.Start(hyperlink.NavigateUri.ToString());
            e.Handled = true;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the datagrid definition you are missing the actual destination itself,i. e the uri itself. You need to define it by using binding property and display the image using content binding property .

```
DataGridHyperlinkColumn Header="CNIC"   Binding="{Binding Path=uri}"
                 ContentBinding="{Binding Path=s_man_image}" Width="100" >
                <DataGridHyperlinkColumn.ElementStyle>
```

Comment: in Binding="{Binding Path=uri}" i replaced "uri" with "s_man_image" which gave me error "Failed to convert resource into Object". i am unable to understand whats happening

Comment: No uri must be placed with the actual uri you are gonna hit.

Comment: can you explain it with help of code, i know i am asking silly type of questions but please if you can.

Comment: s_man_image will be for display purpose to end user but when that image is clicked internally uri/hyperlink will be hit if you provide the uri.